# Understanding Disconnect / Reconnect Process and Error Messages

Tags: pusher

I am trying to implement a feature which notifies the user of disconnections to pusher, and indicates when reconnection has occured.  My first experiment is simply to log changing pusher states to console:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('MY_ACCOUNT_STRING');
pusher.connection.bind('state_change', function(states) {
  console.log(states.current);
});
```

I then refresh the page, get a connection to pusher, disable my internet connection, wait for pusher to detect the disconnection, re-enable my internet connection, and wait for pusher to detect that.  Here's a screenshot of chrome's console output during the process ([click here for a larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qwCe.png)):

[image: chrome console during disconnection]

Here are my questions:

1. It took over a minute, possibly even 2-3 minutes, before the disconnection was detected by pusher.  Is there a way to decrease that time so pusher detects disconnection within 10 or so seconds?
2. Why am I seeing those red errors, and what exactly do they mean?  Is that normal?  I would think with the correct setup the errors would be handled, since a disconnection event is an "expected" exception within the pusher context.
3. What is the 1006 error and why am I seeing that?

Thanks for any help!

### EDIT:

I've been watching the output for a long-standing connection, and I've also seen this a number of times, and would like to know the cause of it, and how I can capture it and handle it?

```
disconnected login.js:146
connecting login.js:146
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":1007,"message":"Server heartbeat missed"}}} pusher.min.js:12
connected
```

Answer (score 3):

That's no normal behavior. Have you had the chance to check this on different machine and network? It looks like a network problem.

#### Question 1.

When I disable wifi it takes pusher 4 seconds to notice and change the state to `disconnected` and then to `unavailable`.

When I re-enable wifi I only get same error as you do on `http://js.pusher.com/2.1.3/sockjs.js`

I've got no idea about the implications of doing so.. but you could try to alter the default timeouts:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('MY_ACCOUNT_STRING',  {
    pong_timeout: 6000, //default = 30000
    unavailable_timeout: 2000 //default = 10000
});
```

#### Question 2.

No idea, I don't think the lib should throw those error's

#### Question 3.

The error's are from the WebSocket protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

```
  1006 is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
  Close control frame by an endpoint.  It is designated for use in
  applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
  connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or
  receiving a Close control frame.

  1007 indicates that an endpoint is terminating the connection
  because it has received data within a message that was not
  consistent with the type of the message (e.g., non-UTF-8 [RFC3629]
  data within a text message).
```

Comment: I ended up emailing pusher support, and they basically said it was normal behavior and there was nothing I could do about it except change the ping pong timeouts.

Comment: Hmm, did they gave any advice about a good value? Or just that you had to experiment with it? Did you manage to try it out on a different network or machine?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work better some places than others.  Basically they said if the native browser socket detection is working properly, it will detect almost instantly.  But it's not 100% reliable, even on new browsers.  Why and in what situations it fails they didn't seem to know.  So if you need to be safe you can put your pong down to every 10s, but it's not recommended because it stresses their servers and I think also can give false positives iirc.  Bottom line seemed to be the underlying technology is not foolproof.